# The meaning of words from an image パシヤ （or パシャ） and しみる

Tags: translation, meaning, words, onomatopoeia

[image]

[image]

What do パシヤ（or パシャ) and しみる mean?

Answer (score 3):

「パシャ」 is the onomatopoeia for the sound made when pressing on the shutter-release button on a camera.

「しみる」 has many meanings, but your image would suggest that the word is being used for the meaning of "I'm deeply moved." or "(Something) is going straight to my heart."